# Cucumber with Micronaut

Tags: java, cucumber, micronaut

I am trying to use Cucumber with Micronaut but the @MicronautTest annotation simply does not work (theApple is not injected - see the code below) when I try to use it with cucumber. If I run it without Cucumber it is OK. Do you have any experience with this? Should it work?

Thanks Ivan

These are the classes

class1

```
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty" },
        features = "src/test/resources"
)
public class TheRunner {
}
```

class2

```
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Value;
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@MicronautTest
public class Steps {

    @Value("apple")
    private String theApple;

//  @Test
//  public void test() {
//     System.out.println("Value: " + theApple);
//  }

    @Given("some text")
    public void some_method_1() {
        System.out.println("Value: " + theApple);
    }

    @When("some text")
    public void some_method_2() {
    }

    @Then("an alarm is raised")
    public void some_method_3() {
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java"
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
    implementation platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime"
    implementation "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api"
    implementation "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client"
    runtimeOnly "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
    testAnnotationProcessor platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    testAnnotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java"
    testImplementation platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")
    testImplementation "io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-junit5"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:${junitVersion}"
    testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-java:$cucumberVersion"
    testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:$cucumberVersion"
}
```

Comment: This won't work. `@Micronaut` is an is a Junit5 extension. Cucumber is using JUnit4. It could be made to work by implementing an `ObjectFactory` for Cucumber though.

Comment: I see the JUnit 4 vs 5 thing. Thx. But what do you mean by the ObjectFactory? Is it a JUnit 5 feature for extending its functionality?

Comment: It's a Cucumber feature used to support dependency injection into your step definitions (effectively what Micronaut is doing).

Comment: I see. Thank you

Comment: Some one get it working with junit 5?

Comment: I found this project https://github.com/david-romero/cucumber-micronaut but only support `@Named` annotation. I'd like something with `@ConfigurationProperties` support too. But i think it's hard to make a fully support class for all annotations possibles

Answer (score 1):

here is my version of ObjectFactory bound with Micronaut. So far, it has been working with all beans declared inside our project.

```java
package com.myproject.libs.cucumber;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import io.cucumber.core.backend.ObjectFactory;
import io.micronaut.context.ApplicationContext;
import io.micronaut.runtime.server.EmbeddedServer;

/**
 * Will start an {@link EmbeddedServer} at the start then stop it at the end of <strong>each</strong> Scenario<br>
 * Will also use the {@link ApplicationContext} to resolve Glue beans
 */
@Slf4j
public final class MicronautObjectFactory implements ObjectFactory {

    private EmbeddedServer embeddedServer;

    @Override
    public void start() {
        log.info("#### Starting EmbeddedServer");
        embeddedServer = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer.class, "test", "cucumber");
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        if (embeddedServer != null) {
            log.info("#### Stopping EmbeddedServer");
            embeddedServer.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T getInstance(final Class<T> beanType) {
        return embeddedServer.getApplicationContext().getBean(beanType);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addClass(final Class<?> aClass) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

You'll still need to

- declare this bean inside `resources/META-INF/services/io.cucumber.core.backend.ObjectFactory` file with simple line `com.myproject.libs.cucumber.MicronautObjectFactory`
- (optional) also add file `resources/cucumber.properties` with values

```
# Cucumber properties to be applied, even when running feature's scenario manually
# https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine#configuration-options
cucumber.publish.quiet=true
cucumber.plugin=json:build/reports/cucumber.json
cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy=long
cucumber.object-factory=com.myproject.libs.cucumber.MicronautObjectFactory
```

- and to facilitate the usage of it, create your own annotation

```java
package com.myproject.libs.cucumber;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.JUNIT_PLATFORM_NAMING_STRATEGY_PROPERTY_NAME;
import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME;
import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.PLUGIN_PUBLISH_QUIET_PROPERTY_NAME;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import org.junit.platform.commons.annotation.Testable;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Inherited
@Documented
@Testable
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "json:build/reports/cucumber.json")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = JUNIT_PLATFORM_NAMING_STRATEGY_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "long")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PUBLISH_QUIET_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "true")
public @interface MicronautCucumber {
}
```

note the dependencies you need:

- io.cucumber:cucumber-java
- io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine
- org.junit.platform:junit-platorm-suite
- io.micronaut:micronaut-context

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful.A small suggestion for the MicronautObjectFactory.stop() method. Add `embeddedServer = null;` at the end of the `if` block. Otherwise Cucumber will fail when it tries to run a second test case in the same suite.