# Cucumber Micronaut test: Embedded gRPC server not starting

Tags: cucumber, junit5, micronaut

> I have solved the original "Multiple possible bean candidates found: [io.micronaut.aop.InterceptorRegistry, io.micronaut.aop.InterceptorRegistry]". See MicronautObjectFactory.start in the repo linked below.]

I'm trying to write some integration tests using Cucumber for a Micronaut application. Micronaut successfully launches its embedded gRPC server when run from the command line (`java -jar ...`). However, when the Cucumber tests are run from the command line (`mvn verify`), Micronaut starts, but not the embedded gRPC server.

As a result the integration test gets an "UNAVAILABLE" gRPC error because there's nothing for the client in the integration test to connect to.

I've used, then modified, information from [Cucumber with Micronaut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58854033/cucumber-with-micronaut) to integrate the two utilities.

Per the advice given in the first comment, there is now a [cucumber-micronaut-bean-failure](https://github.com/mlresnick/cucumber-micronaut-bean-failure) repo with the code. See the README for details.

Comment: I recommend that you create a Github-repo with code that reproduces this issue, too much work for most of us to try to puzzle the peaces together. The not-accepted SO-answer you link to, mentions resources/META-INF/services/io.cucumber.core.backend.ObjectFactory, I can't see that in your question. BR

Comment: @Roar S., thanks for the suggestion. There is now a [repo](https://github.com/mlresnick/cucumber-micronaut-bean-failure) available.